# select where value is zero gives a wrong result

Tags: mysql

```
create table arts (
    `id` int(11) auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(255),
    `source` varchar(255),
    primary key (`id`)
) engine = innodb, charset utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_croatian_ci;

insert into arts (name,source) values("lorem","lorem");
insert into arts (name,source) values("lorem","lorem");
insert into arts (name,source) values("lorem","lorem");

select * from arts where name = 0;
```

Result: `3` rows

Why this happens? There is no `0` values in any field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is implicit conversion involved `lorem` -> INT -> `0`:

```
select * from arts where name = '0';  => 0 rows (no implicit conversion)
select * from arts where name = 0;    => 3 rows (varchar(255) -> INT)
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e4707a3a2e0f675c99d86737acc6820d)**